# Проверка существования объекта в node.js

Tags: javascript

Есть объект:

```js
{
  "object": 123
}
```

Но не всегда выходит так, что `object` существует. Как мне проверить на существование `object`? Пробовал и `typeof` и

```js
function type(value) {
  const regex = /^\[object (\S+?)\]$/;
  const matches = Object.prototype.toString.call(value).match(regex) || [];
              
  return (matches[1] || 'undefined').toLowerCase();
}
```

Всё равно node.js ловит ошибку...

Answer (score 1):

1. Способ с hasOwnProperty

   const tmp = {
   "object": 123
   }

   tmp.hasOwnProperty('object');     // => true
2. Оператор in

   const tmp = {
   "object": 123
   }

   'object' in tmp ;
3. Проверка через undefined

   const tmp = {
   "object": 123
   }

   tmp.object !== undefined;     // => true

Comment: пробовал всё это. Прописал условие, что если это существует, то добавляем его обработку. Потом выдаёт ошибку cannot read property of “undefined”

Comment: https://youtu.be/AgK2LcJ_Wp4 показал тут как проверил все действия)

Comment: В с type(value) конце вместо `==` надо было `!==`. Ошибка выскочила. Могу записать, если надо

Comment: причина вашей ошибки не в ваших проверках, а в том, что после них вы делаете `items = items[x].tr` и уходите в следующую итерацию с совсем другими данными

Comment: @nörbörnën в таком случае, как мне правильно будет продолжить распаковку массива? Ведь массив с данными items закончился, а продолжение в items[x].tr

Comment: без понятия. ваши данные, вам видней